# Disabling read-only mode for large folders

Tags: directory, readonly

I have large folder (2.57 GB) in my File Explorer and it is currently in read-only mode. I have tried disabling this mode by right clicking on the folder, going to 'Properties', clicking on the Read-only box (under 'Attributes') to switch it off, then clicking Apply. After this, a progress bar shows taking about 6 minutes to disable read-only mode on all the files, and once thats done I press 'Apply' then 'Ok'. However after that, if  I recheck the folder properties the Read-only box is stilled ticked.

I've tried multiple times to disable this mode with the method above, yet it never seems to work. What is causing the issue? Is there an alternative way I can disable read-only mode on this folder?